# set weights of keras layers

Tags: python, keras, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to do the game Snake using genetic algorithm and Keras.

My problem, right now, is the following:

I create the initial population of snake with X genes each, where X is NUMBER_WEIGHTS:

```
INPUT = 24
NEURONS_HIDDEN_1 = 16
NEURONS_HIDDEN_2 = 16
OUTPUT = 3
NUMBER_WEIGHTS = INPUT * NEURONS_HIDDEN_1 + NEURONS_HIDDEN_1 * NEURONS_HIDDEN_2 + NEURONS_HIDDEN_2 * OUTPUT
```

and i create the initial population like this:

```
population = numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(-1, 1, step=0.01), size=(config.NUMBER_OF_POPULATION, config.NUMBER_WEIGHTS))
```

I have a for cycle that for each snake inside my population start the pygame script, inside the pygame script i have the Keras NN, but i would like to pass the weights that i have generated to the NN.

My NN is like that for now:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD

from utils import config
def neural_net(weights):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(config.INPUT, input_shape=(config.INPUT,)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    # create the dense input layer
    # model.add(Dense(config.INPUT, activation=keras.activations.relu(4,), input_dim=4))
    # model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    # create first hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(config.NEURONS_HIDDEN_1, input_shape=(config.INPUT,)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    # create second hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(config.NEURONS_HIDDEN_2, input_shape=(config.NEURONS_HIDDEN_1,)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    # create output layer
    model.add(Dense(config.OUTPUT, input_shape=(config.NEURONS_HIDDEN_2,)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    print(weights.shape[0])
    model.set_weights(weights)

    # create the optimizer (Stochastic Gradient Descent)
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=0.0, momentum=0.0, nesterov=False)
    # Use mean squared error loss and SGD as optimizer
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=sgd)

    return model
```

But model.set_weights(weights) return this exception:

```
File "neural_network.py", line 28, in neural_net
    model.set_weights(weights)
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 527, in set_weights
    K.batch_set_value(tuples)
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2960, in batch_set_value
    tf_keras_backend.batch_set_value(tuples)
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3323, in batch_set_value
    x.assign(np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype(x)))
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 819, in assign
    self._shape.assert_is_compatible_with(value_tensor.shape)
  File "C:\Users\Davide\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 1110, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (24, 24) and () are incompatible

Process finished with exit code 1
```

We have 24 input * 16 neuros on the hidden layer one, then 16 neurons * 16 neurons on layer hidden 2 and finally 16 neurons hidden layer 2 * 3 inputs = 24*16+16*16+16*3 = 688

And

```
print(weights.shape[0])
```

is 688. So why i can't set the correct weights?

First time doing a project using AI, so i may have completely misunderstood how this works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there is a shape mismatch in the weights of model and the weights you are providing. You need to provide weights corresponding to each layer as shown in the example below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

def create_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28),name='flatten'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',name='dense1'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2,name = 'dropout'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name='dense2')
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), #'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

# create model architecture and compile
model = create_model()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test) 

#saving weights
model.save_weights('./model_weights', save_format='tf')

#layer weights from the model 
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers])
print(layer_dict)

# creating the same model architecture and compile
loaded_model = create_model()

# This initializes the variables used by the optimizers,
# as well as any stateful metric variables
loaded_model.train_on_batch(x_train[:1], y_train[:1])

# loading the weights from base_model
for layer in loaded_model.layers:
  layer_name = layer.name
  print(layer.name)
  layer.set_weights(layer_dict[layer_name].get_weights())

# accessing weights of a layer by its name
layer_dict[layer_name].get_weights() 

# check the evaluation before and after are same
loaded_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

print(loaded_model.weights)

print(model.weights)
```

Hope this example will give some insights for you to solve your problem.
Full code is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Sequential_set_weights.ipynb) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But i'm still unable to understand how that works.

My idea is that i want 24 input neurons connected to 16 hidden neurons. Then i want those 16 neurons connected to another hidden layer of 16 hidden neurons. Finally the 16 hidden neurons connected to the 3 output neurons. So my input neurons why the should have 24x24 weights?

Comment: did you check `model.summary`? does it show 688 as total trainable params? you also need to add bias. If you query `model.weights`, you will see how many weights and bias required for your model.